# Solve the recurrence relation: $na_n = (n-4)a_{n-1} + 12n H_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion, harmonic-numbers

I want to solve
$$ na_n = (n-4)a_{n-1} + 12n H_n,\quad n\geq 5,\quad a_0=a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=0. $$

Does anyone have an idea, what could be substituted for $a_n$ to get an expression, which one could just sum up? We should use
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{m} H_k = \binom{n+1}{m+1} H_{n+1} - \frac{1}{m+1} \binom{n+1}{m+1} $$
to simplify the result.

Comment: Consider the generating function. You will end up with a first order differential equation from that recursion.

Comment: $$a_n=\frac{12}{25} (n+1) \left(5 H_{n+1}-1\right)-\frac{600}{n(n-1) (n-2) (n-3) }$$

Comment: @Raffaele. Could you post an answer to explain your result wich is perfectly correct ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici RSolve[{n a[n] == (n - 4) a[n - 1] + 12 n HarmonicNumber[n], 
  a[4] == 0}, a[n], n]

Comment: @Raffaele I have to solve it without CAS, so there has to be a method to get to this solution.

Comment: @question Would be nice if you tell us the context of this question. Why do you think you can use the last equality? Are you dealing with finite calculus?

Comment: Are you sure the problem has a closed form?

Comment: @Phicar there is no context, it is just an exercise from a class about analyzing algorithms. The equality is given as a hint to simplify the result

Comment: @Raffaele it should have because it is an exercise given by a teacher

Comment: Your formula contains a typo $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{m} H_k = \binom{n+1}{m+1} H_n - \frac{1}{m+1} \binom{n}{m+1} $$ should be $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{m} H_k = \binom{n+1}{m+1} H_{n+1} - \frac{1}{m+1} \binom{n}{m+1} $$

Comment: yes that is true, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different approach: Consider the change of variable $b_n=a_{n+4},$ so that the only initial condition is given by $b_0=0.$ Notice that the equation becomes
$$(n+5)a_{n+5}-(n+4)a_{n+4}+3a_{n+4}-12(n+5)H_{n+5}=0,$$
$$(n+5)b_{n+1}-(n+4)b_{n}+3b_{n}-12(n+5)H_{n+5}=0,$$
take $f(x)=(x+4)b_x$ so that $$\Delta (f)=f(x+1)-f(x)=(x+5)b_{x+1}-(x+4)b_x,$$
so we get that $$\Delta (f(x))=\frac{-3}{x+4}f(x)+12(x+5)H_{x+5}.$$
This looks like variation of parameters, check [Remark 10](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2019/10967/pdf/LIPIcs-MFCS-2019-23.pdf).
We get then that the solution becomes
$$f(x)=\sum _{u=1}^{x-1}\left (\prod _{t=u+1}^{x-1} \left (1-\frac{3}{t+4}\right )\right )\cdot \left (12(u+5)H_{u+5}\right ),$$
notice that the product becomes
$$\left (\prod _{t=u+1}^{x-1} \left (1-\frac{3}{t+4}\right )\right )=\left (\prod _{t=u+1}^{x-1} \left (\frac{t+1}{t+4}\right )\right )=\frac{(u+2)(u+3)(u+4)}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)},$$
replacing we get
$$f(x)=12\sum _{u=0}^{x-1}\frac{\binom{u+5}{4}4!H_{u+5}}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}=\frac{12\cdot 4!}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}\left (\sum _{u=0}^{x+4}\binom{u}{4}H_{u}-\sum _{u=0}^4\binom{u}{4}H_{u}\right )$$
using your professors hint(which is a good exercise of integration by parts), we get that
$$f(x)=\frac{12\cdot 4!}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}\left (\binom{x+5}{5}H_{x+5}-\frac{1}{5}\binom{x+5}{5}-\frac{25}{12}\right )$$
Taking back the change of variable, meaning plugging at $x-4,$ we get
$$na_n=f(n-4)=\frac{12\cdot 4!}{(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)}\left (\binom{n+1}{5}H_{n+1}-\frac{1}{5}\binom{n+1}{5}-\frac{25}{12}\right )$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution is perfect, there is just a little mistake in the one line before the last. It should be $\frac{1}{5}\binom{x+5}{5}$ instead of $\frac{1}{5}\binom{x+4}{5}$, then you can write out the binomial coefficients and will get exactly the solution that @Raffaele suggested.

Comment: @question You are right, i did not verify it from the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are more details for @Phicar's suggested approach.
Let $A(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function of $(a_n)$.
Then $z A'(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n z^n$, and the recurrence relation implies that
\begin{align}
z A'(z) 
&= \sum_{n \ge 5} \left((n-4)a_{n-1} + 12n H_n\right) z^n \\
&= z \sum_{n \ge 5} (n-1) a_{n-1} z^{n-1} - 3 z \sum_{n \ge 5} a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + 12z \sum_{n \ge 5} n H_n z^{n-1} \\
&= z \cdot z A'(z) - 3z A(z) + 12z\left(\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{-\log(1-z)}{1-z}\right) -\sum_{n=1}^4 n H_n z^{n-1}\right) \\
&= z^2 A'(z) - 3z A(z) + 12z\left(\frac{1-\log(1-z)}{(1-z)^2} -1-3z-\frac{11}{2}z^2-\frac{25}{3}z^4\right)
\end{align}
The [resulting solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%20A%27%5Bz%5D%20%3D%3Dz%5E2%20A%27%5Bz%5D%20-%203z%20A%5Bz%5D%20%2B%2012z%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Clog%281-z%29%7D%7B%281-z%29%5E2%7D%20-1-3z-%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B2%7Dz%5E2-%5Cfrac%7B25%7D%7B3%7Dz%5E4%5Cright%29) for $A(z)$ is messy, so there must be a better way.

Comment: Given that it's $na_n = (n-4)a_{n-1} + 12n H_n$, isn't the substitution missing a factor $\frac 1n$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Thats exactly what I tried, but I thought too that the solution looked not clean enough to be right.

Comment: I went on with your hint and found the generating function and it works. Too bad there is no closed form for $a_n$

Comment: Sorry, it seems that my comment went to a hard problem(I was expecting something easier, did not realized the shift for the initial conditions that made it look bad). You can solve it without passing to the generating function.

Answer (score 1):

*Given by a CAS.*

Isuppose that is missing the condition $a_3=0$.

Starting from $n=5$, the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{137}{25},\frac{1009}{150},\frac{17953}{2450},\frac{151717}{19600},\frac{
   170875}{21168},\frac{1474379}{176400},\frac{3751927}{435600},\frac{20228477}{22869
   00}\right\}$$ is not recognized by $OEIS$.

Being totally stuck, I used a CAS without conditions and got, after a lot of simplifications,
$$a_n=\frac{(-3 n^4+22 n^3-69 n^2+194 n+288+96 C) } {4 (n-3) (n-2) (n-1) n }+$$ $$\frac{12 (n-4) (n+1) \left(n^2-3 n+6\right) H_{n+1} } {4 (n-3) (n-2) (n-1) n }$$

For $n=0,1,2,3$, this leads to indeterminate forms. For $n=4$
$$a_4=C+\frac{25}{4}=0 \implies C=-\frac{25}{4}$$ leading to
$$a_n=(n-4)\frac{12 (n+1) \left(n^2-3 n+6\right) H_{n+1}-(n-3) \left(3 n^2-n+26\right) } {4 (n-3) (n-2) (n-1) n }$$ which is identical to what @Raffaele wrote in a comment.

Asymptotically,
$$a_n=3 \left(\gamma -\frac{1}{4}\right)+3 \log (n)+\frac{11}{2 n}-\frac{25}{4
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

*I would really like to know how, starting from scratch, we could arrive to the result.*

Comment: Yeah Wolfram gives me nearly the same result, but with no hint on how to get to this solution.

Comment: I solved with the @robpratt hint. Look my answer, even if I didn't find a closed form for $a_n$

Answer (score 1):

I have one different idea, variation of constant.

If one has a recurrence relation of the form
$$ a_{n+1} = \alpha_n a_n + \beta_n,\quad n\geq 0, $$
then we can make the ansatz
$$ a_n^{(p)} = C_n \prod_{j=}^{n-1} \alpha_j $$
and get
$$ C_{n+1} \prod_{j=0}^n \alpha_j = \alpha_n C_n \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \alpha_j + \beta_n $$
$$ \Longrightarrow C_{n+1} = C_n + \frac{\beta_n}{\prod_{j=0}^n \alpha_j} $$
$$ \Longrightarrow C_n = \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{\beta_l}{\prod_{j=0}^l \alpha_j} + C_0$$
and therefore
$$ a_n = \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{\beta_l}{\prod_{j=0}^l \alpha_j} \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \alpha_j + C \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \alpha_j = \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{12 H_{l+1}}{\prod_{j=0}^l \frac{j-3}{j+1}} \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{j-3}{j+1} + C \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{j-3}{j+1} \\= \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} 12 H_{l+1} \prod_{j=l+1}^{n-1} \frac{j-3}{j+1} + C \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{j-3}{j+1},$$
if we define
$$ \alpha_n = \frac{n-3}{n+1},\qquad \beta_n = 12 H_{n+1}.$$
I do not know how to continue from here, maybe someone knows how to simplify this terms to get to the solution?

Comment: (+1) I think your approach is good and essentially is the same as the answer I posted down there.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^n } $ be the generating function of the solution of the recurrence.
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {na_n x^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {n + 1} \right)a_n x^{n + 1}  - 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_{n - 1} x^n } }  + 
12\sum\limits_{n = 5}^\infty  {na_n x^n } H_n 
$$
which gives the following DE
$$
xf'\left( x \right) = x^2 f'\left( x \right) - 3xf\left( x \right)-\frac{2 x \left(50 x^5-67 x^4+2 x^3+3 x^2+6 x+6 \log (1-x)\right)}{(x-1)^2}$$
Whose solution is
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{75 (x-1)^2} \left(-7553 x^5+3750 x^5 \log (1-x)+\\+24040 x^4-18750 x^4 \log (1-x)-29405 x^3+37500 x^3 \log (1-x)+\\+16830 x^2-37500 x^2 \log (1-x)-3840 x+18750 x \log (1-x)-3840 \log (1-x)\right)$$

Coefficients of the MacLaurin expansion of $f(x)$ are
$$0,0,0,0,0,\frac{137}{5},\frac{578}{15},\frac{1667}{35},\frac{395}{7},\frac{41137}{630},\frac{13007}{175},\frac{964849}{11550},\ldots$$

There is no closed form for $a_n$, though.

Comment: so it seems that we cannot use this method to get a closed form, maybe my idea with the variation of constant works (see last post)?

Comment: Looks like $$[x^n]\frac{x^m}{(1-x)^2}=\max(n-m+1,0)$$ and $$[x^n]\frac{x^m\log(1-x)}{(1-x)^2}=\left(n-m-1 - \frac{1}{n-m} - (n - m+1) H_{n-m-1}\right)[n \ge m+1].$$